# Laravel eloquent get conditional result in where

Tags: laravel, eloquent, relation

I have this table `participations`

```
| active   | customer_id   | doctor_id
| -------- | ------------- | ----------
| true     | 1             | 5         
| true     | 2             | 5         
| true     | 3             | 5
```

I'm trying to get all the doctors except those who are already assigned to a customer.

The participation relation in my doctor model:

```
public function participations() {
  return $this->hasMany(Participation::class);
}
```

My doctors model have this scope method:

```
public function scopeOnlyAvailable($query, $customerId = 1) {
  return $query->whereHas('participations', function($query) use ($customerId) {
    $query->where('customer_id', '!=', $customerId);
  }
}
```

With this scope i don't get the dataset with the customer_id 1, but all other datasets. Thats the problem, because they contain the same doctor (which i dont want).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`whereDoesntHave()`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#querying-relationship-absence) method:

```
return $query->whereDoesntHave('participations', function($query) use ($customerId) {
    $query->where('customer_id', $customerId);
}
```